# Making a Secure Password Program in python 3.4 using while loops

Tags: python

How do i make a python password program that asks the user to enter a password and it checks that the password is at least 8 characters, one number, one capital letter, and one lowercase letter.  If it is missing one of these, it will print out a statement telling them what they need to add to make the password secure. 
my code so far:

```
incorrectPassword= True
while incorrectPassword:
    password = input("type in your password")
    if len(password < 8):
        print("your password must be 8 characters long")
    elif noNum(password == False):
        print("you need a number in your password")
    elif noCap(password == False):
        print("you need a capital letter in your password")
    elif NoLow(password == False):
```

Comment: its an assignment for my computer science class and i have tired to make variables to print out when the user types in a password but im stuck on how to make it check for more than 8 characters and if it has a capital letter. and that is the assignment

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you've tried and the way in which it fails (wrong results, error message, etc.).

Comment: Can you read that code?? I can't, please fix it.

Comment: Go to python.org and read the sections on control structures, assignments, and expressions. There is currently too much that's wrong with this code to give an answer that would be useful to other users. I have voted to close.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To check if the password string contains a number, capital letter or similar you can use regular expression, here is a nice tool to test and learn that [RegExr] (http://www.regexr.com/).

It is a good practice to have a function that will check, validate your input if there you need to do that more than once e.q. in a while loop.

```
import re

def checkPassword(password):
    """
    Validate the password
    """
    if len(password) < 8:
        # Password to short
        print("Your password must be 8 characters long.")
        return False
    elif not re.findall(r'\d+', password):
        # Missing a number
        print("You need a number in your password.")
        return False
    elif not re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', password):
        # Missing at least one capital letter
        print("You need a capital letter in your password.")
        return False
    else:
        # All good
        print("All good")
        return True

# Promt user to enter valid password
passwordValid = False
while not passwordValid:
    password = input("Type in your password: ")
    passwordValid = checkPassword(password)
```

Comment: Regular expressions are severe overkill for this.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 you are right about the overkill, but since we're talking about string of 8 characters it's not that severe. For instance, you could lower the string and check if the two matched (to check capital letter).

Comment: The fact that it's for simple checks on short strings is what makes it severe overkill. Python has several basic functions and methods that would be ideal for a problem like this. I just hope this question isn't for a school assignment, because the professor will know something is up if the asker uses this code.

Comment: I see that it is indeed [for a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402580/making-a-secure-password-program-in-python-3-4-using-while-loops/29402989#comment46980678_29402580). Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

`len(password - 8)` first tries to compare `8` to the password the user entered, which won't work. You have to find the length of the password first, then compare it to `8`: `len(password) - 8`.

Things like `noNum(password == False)` will send a boolean to the `noNum()` function I presume you have somewhere, which probably isn't what it needs. You'd probably want `noNum(password) == True` - since `noNum()` should return `True` if the passed string doesn't contain a number.

That said, Python has string methods for determining whether a string is uppercase, lowercase, or digital (containing only digits). Use these to evaluate the given password, along with the `any()` function.

```
incorrectPassword= True
while incorrectPassword:
    password = input("type in your password: ")
    if len(password) < 8:
        print("your password must be 8 characters long")
    elif not any(i.isdigit() for i in password):
        print("you need a number in your password")
    elif not any(i.isupper() for i in password):
        print("you need a capital letter in your password")
    elif not any(i.islower() for i in password):
        print("you need a lowercase letter in your password")
    else:
        incorrectPassword = False
```

Comment: in your case any with the check isupper/islower/isdigit is slower than regex.

`timeit.timeit('re.findall(r"[A-Z]+", "asdfqweR")', setup="import re")` runs in 1.1296026709896978, where `timeit.timeit('any(i.isupper() for i in "asdfqweR")')` runs in 1.2718868080119137

Comment: Are you familiar with the phrase "premature optimization is the root of all evil"? Besides, I tested each version with `perf_counter()` and mine takes 1-5 tenths of a millisecond while yours takes 7-8 tenths of a millisecond, for strings between a few and a few hundred characters long.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True :
      name = input('Enter user name')
      if name != 'leela':
              continue
      password = input('hello,leela Enter password')
       if password='sana':
              break
print('Access granted')
```

Comment: if the name contain four digits and password contain also four digits only

Comment: then we will execute  the programe